# Is it haram to say ''Oh my lord'' or ''Oh Lord''

Tags: practical-islam, shirk, children

I am 12 years old and I said "oh my Lord" AND  "OH LORD".

**Is this considered shirk or am I disrespecting Allah?**

Comment: If by Lord, your intention is to invoke Allah then you are not committing shirk. You are simply referring to God in the language you are most comfortable with. But also note that the Salah (prayer) can be only in the Arabic language whereas duas  have no such restrictions on them.

Answer (score 0):

In Islam the one and perfect name for God is **ALLAH**. There are 99 names of Allah.

> Allah the Almighty, says in the Qur’an a kareem: ‘Wa lillahil asma’il
>   husna fad’uhu bi ha’ ‘And to Allah belong all the best names, so call
>   Him by them’ [‘al A’raf; 180]

Although if your intentions or words of saying **LORD** is for Allah then its not a Sin but in short Recommended way or u should say the word **Allah** or others beautiful names.

Answer (score 0):

"oh lord" This is the english translation in Arabic we say"ya ilahi".when we are praying to Allah we use this word .it is a very beautiful addressing word "ya ilahi" is not haram when we use it as a "oh my lord"we pray to Allah oh my lord please help me show me right path

Comment: Usually "Oh Lord" is a translation of "Ya Rabb". "Ya ilaahi" is rather something like "Oh my God" or better "Oh my Lord" which both would be a better translation of "Ya Rabbi" as ilaah is the Arabic synonym of Deity.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using it like a reactionary phrase like "omg!" or "Oh no!" it's fine. Even if you say it when you're praying to god, it's fine. "Lord" is not a christian word. It's an English word. It's not haram to speak English.

If you open up an english quran you'll find the word "Lord" a lot.